# Using recursive CTE to resolve a group, not hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm trying to do a recursive CTE in SQL Server with the following example data

```
Class        Student
------       ------
English      Sally   <- Sally is what were searching for
English      Peter   <- Peter's on same Class as Sally
Swedish      Peter   <- Found because Peter's on this class
Dutch        Peter   <- Found because Peter's on this class
Finnish      Harry   <- Not found, no relation to class or student
Swedish      Tim     <- Found because Peter's on Swedish class
Spanish      Lauren  <- Not found, no relation to class or student
Spanish      Colin   <- Not found, no relation to class or student
```

So I need a CTE, to which I give 'Sally' as parameter, and it will find out all different classes related to Sally, then all Students related to Classes that Sally is in, then all classes related to students in the same classes as Sally, and so on until no more rows found.

But I just cannot figure out how to write the joins, this is what I tried but failed miserably:

```
WITH myCTE (Class, Student) AS
(
    SELECT Class, Student FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.Student= 'Sally'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Class, t.Student FROM TABLE1 t
    JOIN myCTE t2 ON t2.Class = t.Class
)
SELECT * FROM myCTE
```

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Comment: Expected result in this case is all fields in the example data, because there's 'A' and 'B' for value 1, and there's values 1,2 and 3 in Field1 for values 'B'. The problem in my example code is that it loops infinitely, and doesnt stop when no new occurrences are found.

Comment: I think your dataset is too small to make it clear what you're trying to do.  Please add some rows e.g. (4,C) (3,D) (10,A) and tell us what the query _should_ output from that input (and why).

Comment: Ok, edited and also wrote what rows should be found. I could do this with while loop or cursor, but i think CTE would be more professional way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you've got infinite recursion: Sally takes English with Peter, who takes English with Sally, who takes English with Peter...

Once you've sorted that out, you'll need an additional query in your recursive CTE. You're currently joining on `Class` to get the other students in the same class, but you also need to join on `Student` to get the other classes for the students.

Something like this should work:

```
WITH cteSource As
(
   SELECT
      Class,
      Student,
      -- Create a unique ID for each record:
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Student, Class) As ID
   FROM
      TABLE1
),
cteRecursive (Class, Student, IDPath) As
(
   SELECT
      Class,
      Student,
      -- Used to exclude records we've already visited:
      Convert(varchar(max), '/' + Convert(varchar(10), ID) + '/')
   FROM
      cteSource
   WHERE
      Student = 'Sally'

   UNION ALL

   -- Students in the same class:
   SELECT
      T.Class,
      T.Student,
      R.IDPath + Convert(varchar(10), T.ID) + '/'
   FROM
      cteSource As T
      INNER JOIN cteRecursive As R
      ON T.Class = R.Class
   WHERE
      CharIndex('/' + Convert(varchar(10), t.ID) + '/', R.IDPath) = 0

   UNION ALL

   -- Other classes for the students:
   SELECT
      T.Class,
      T.Student,
      R.IDPath + Convert(varchar(10), T.ID) + '/'
   FROM
      cteSource As T
      INNER JOIN cteRecursive As R
      ON T.Student = R.Student
   WHERE
      CharIndex('/' + Convert(varchar(10), t.ID) + '/', R.IDPath) = 0
)
SELECT
   Class,
   Student,
   IDPath
FROM
   cteRecursive
;
```

With your test data, you'll get the following results:

```
English   Sally   /7/
English   Peter   /7/5/
Dutch     Peter   /7/5/4/
Swedish   Peter   /7/5/6/
Swedish   Tim     /7/5/6/8/
Dutch     Peter   /7/5/6/4/
Swedish   Peter   /7/5/4/6/
Swedish   Tim     /7/5/4/6/8/
```

If you're using SQL 2008 or higher, you might get better performance if you make the `IDPath` a `HierarchyID`, but you'd need to test with your real data.

**EDIT**
You might need to change the final select to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   Class,
   Student
FROM
   cteRecursive
```

to deal with cases where there are multiple paths to the same record. For example, "Dutch/Peter", "Swedish/Peter" and "Swedish/Tim" all appear twice.

Comment: Yes, I gave it a try and it seemed to work! I'll test it more tomorrow and accept your answer if it is the way to go. Thanks!