# Using recursive CTE to group all children of list of parents

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, common-table-expression

I have a table with two columns - ChildPersonId and ParentPersonId.  The same ID cannot be in both columns.

```
CREATE TABLE Relationship
 (PkId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, ChildPersonId int, GuardianPersonId int)

INSERT INTO Relationship (ChildPersonId, GuardianPersonId) VALUES
(42,24),(42,25),(42,56),(42,56),(43,24),(43,25),(43,26),(43,27),
(43,56),(44,29),(44,30),(45,31),(45,33),(46,34),(47,35),(48,36),
(48,37),(49,36),(49,37),(50,38),(50,39),(51,38),(51,39),(52,40),
(52,41),(53,40),(53,41),(57,24),(57,25),(57,26),(57,27),(57,56),
(63,24),(63,25),(63,26),(63,27),(63,56),(63,59),(64,59),(64,61),
(65,61),(65,62)
```

I want a query where I can pass a ChildPersonId and return ALL related children based on the relationships defined in the data.  So if a child has a parent, I need to then find all OTHER children of that parent, then with those children find their parents and then with those parents, find children...you get the recursive picture.

The query in the link below ALMOST works, but falls way short in terms of performance:

[Using recursive CTE to resolve a group, not hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625944/using-recursive-cte-to-resolve-a-group-not-hierarchy)

The below example actual does return the results I want:

```
SELECT ChildPersonId FROM Relationship M5 INNER JOIN
(SELECT GuardianPersonId FROM Relationship M4 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT ChildPersonId FROM Relationship M3 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT GuardianPersonId FROM Relationship M2 INNER JOIN
   (SELECT ChildPersonId FROM Relationship m1 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT GuardianPersonId FROM Relationship
      WHERE ChildPersonId = 42) g1
       ON m1.GuardianPersonId = g1.GuardianPersonId) c1
    ON m2.ChildPersonId = c1.ChildPersonId) g2
   ON m3.GuardianPersonId = g2.GuardianPersonId) c2
  ON m4.ChildPersonId = c2.ChildPersonId) g3
 ON m5.GuardianPersonId = g3.GuardianPersonId
 GROUP BY ChildPersonId
```

However, this is ugly code and I will only recurse as many times as I am willing to cut & paste.

Can anyone tip me off to the Recursive CTE logic I need to pull this off - without the WHERE clause in the above example that is crushing the execution plan?

The link [Getting all the children of a parent using MSSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041814/getting-all-the-children-of-a-parent-using-mssql-query) shows another method, but doesn't return ChildPersonIds 64 and 65 - it doesn't seem to recurse far enough.

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, a conventional CTE approach will match all but person ids 64 and 65. The approach easily finds element 63. It fails to find 64 and 65 because there is no recursive path to reach either directly.

For instance, 64 is not reached because the only link is to 63 through parent 59. However, 59 is not linked to any other element since it is basically one of multiple root nodes in the tree. Additionally, 65 is not reached because the only path to it is to find 64 as stated above, then traverse through its parent 61 (also a root node) to it's other child 65.

Conventional CTE recursion will not find those alternate paths, so I have included a traditional approach as well as an extension to also iterate parental siblings as a relationship path. This extension need more than just CTE due to the inability to exit the recursive condition due to the data structure.

### Conventional CTE Approach

```
DECLARE @ChildPersonId INT = 42
; WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ChildPersonId,
        GuardianPersonId
    FROM Relationship R
    WHERE ChildPersonId = @ChildPersonId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        R.ChildPersonId,
        R.GuardianPersonId
    FROM cte
        INNER JOIN Relationship R
            ON cte.GuardianPersonId = R.ChildPersonId
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    R.ChildPersonId
FROM cte
    INNER JOIN Relationship R
        ON cte.GuardianPersonId = R.GuardianPersonId
```

**The conventional approach will yield**

```
ChildPersonId
-------------
42
43
57
63
```

### Extension to Conventional Approach

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_GetRelations(
    @ChildPersonId INT
) RETURNS @Results TABLE (
    ChildPersonId INT
)
AS 
BEGIN
    ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT
            ChildPersonId,
            GuardianPersonId
        FROM Relationship R
        WHERE ChildPersonId = @ChildPersonId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            R.ChildPersonId,
            R.GuardianPersonId
        FROM cte
            INNER JOIN Relationship R
                ON cte.GuardianPersonId = R.ChildPersonId
    )
        INSERT @Results
            SELECT DISTINCT
                R.ChildPersonId
            FROM cte
                INNER JOIN Relationship R
                    ON cte.GuardianPersonId = R.GuardianPersonId
    DECLARE @Rows INT = -1
    WHILE @Rows <> 0 BEGIN
        INSERT @Results
            SELECT DISTINCT
                C.ChildPersonId
            FROM @Results A
                INNER JOIN Relationship B
                    ON A.ChildPersonId = B.ChildPersonId
                INNER JOIN Relationship C
                    ON B.GuardianPersonId = C.GuardianPersonId
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Results WHERE ChildPersonId = C.ChildPersonId)
        SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT
    END
    RETURN
END
GO

SELECT A.ChildPersonId FROM f_GetRelations(42) A
```

**The output of this method yields a match to your expected output**

```
ChildPersonId
-------------
42
43
57
63
64
65
```